# How to get the baseline measurement in time series data?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, model-evaluation

I have a time series data of bike's rentals in which each row represents a specific hour and a number of bikes rented in that specific hour. The task is to predict the rentals for the last 10 days (of each hour) based on the historical data of the first 20 days of that month.

Sample of the data:

```
# datetime                 season holiday workingday   temp  humidity windspeed count 
1 2011-01-01 00:00:00      1       0          0        9.84       81    0.0000      3
2 2011-01-01 01:00:00      1       0          0        9.02       80    0.0000      8
3 2011-01-01 02:00:00      1       0          0        9.02       80    0.0000      5
```

I have already built the model and now I wonder how do I know the baseline measurement so that I can say my model is X% better than the baseline measurements ?

In general, how could I measure the quality of my model based on the training set I have ?

Comment: The most obvious a baseline would probably be the *overall* average number of bikes rented per hour.

Comment: Either that or you could break it down by hour or day of the week or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

As was noted in the comments you could use an average.  Other alternatives would be a naive forecast (just the last value projected forward) or seasonal naive (last seasonal period repeated).

Additionally, the previous M4 competition used the average of simple exponential smoothing, double exponential smoothing, and damped double exponential smoothing all averaged together as the benchmark so you could try that out as well.

Judging your model can be done by doing [time series cross validation](https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html) on it and which ever is the best performing for whatever error metric you use is the best model.